# Resharper unit test debugging - don't break on thrown exceptions

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I debug a test suite using Resharper, the execution breaks on exceptions several times before getting to my breakpoint.
The thrown exceptions are expected exceptions to be caught by the `[ExpectedException]` attribute.

Is there any way in Visual Studio or Resharper to make the debugger break on only the breakpoints that I manually set?

Comment: There's no such setting in ReSharper. I think it's probably a VS thing: you use ReSharper to trigger the tests, but the debugging experience is fully in VS's remit.